# Plotting a distribution graph in R with abs value

Tags: r, statistics

The z-score is $|Z| > 2$ and code shown below. The distribution graph is blank and did not show the lower and upper bounds.

[image: distribution plot]

```
mu1 = 0
sigma1 = 1
z.lbscore_d <- abs(2)
z.ubscore_d <- abs(2)

# Draw the normal distribution
range.d = seq(mu1-5*sigma1, mu1 + 5*sigma1, 0.01) 
y.d = dnorm(range.d, mu1, sigma1)
plot(range.d, y.d, type='l', ylim=c(0,max(y.d)+0.01), axes = FALSE)
axis(1, at = seq(mu1-5*sigma1, mu1 + 5*sigma1,sigma1))

# Add area to the middle
d <- range.d > z.lbscore_d & range.d < z.ubscore_d
lines(range.d, y.d)
polygon(z.lbscore_d, range.d[d], z.ubscore_d), c(0, y.d[d], 0), col = "red")

area <- pnorm(z.ubscore_d, mu1, sigma1) - pnorm(z.lbscore_d, mu1, sigma1)
result <- paste("P(", z.lbscore_d, "< IQ <", z.ubscore_d,") =", signif(area, digits = 4))
mtext(result, 5)
```

Comment: `sum(d)` is zero, fix this first.

Comment: In calculus, the area under a single point is 0. In your sample data, your lower-bound (`z.lbscore_d`) and upper-bound (`z.ubscore_d`) are identical at `2`, so effectively your "range" from lower-to-upper bounds is a single point. Ergo nothing is found.

Comment: In addition to the previous comments, you have an inconsistency here: Your question asks to shade and calculate the area where |Z| > 2, but the code `d <- range.d > z.lbscore_d & range.d < z.ubscore_d` is indicating where |Z| < 2. You'll need to clarify which of these options you want.